# Unable to update list inside subscribe in xamarin firebase

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms, system.reactive

I have been trying to use firebase in xamarin forms app. I am using [this](https://github.com/rlamasb/Firebase.Xamarin) nuget package (which uses [system.reactive](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET)) to consume firebase API.

here is what I am doing.

```
public List<Files> FilesList { get; set; }
private void GetData()
{
    var updatedData = "";
    var firebase = new FirebaseClient("<firebase URL>");
    data.Text = "";
    var observable = firebase
        .Child("filesdb")
        .AsObservable<fileInfo>()
        .Subscribe(d =>
        {
            updatedData += "Updated " + d.Object.name + "\n";
            Debug.WriteLine(d.Object.name); //executes only once if I uncomment the following line otherwise executes as many times as I have records in database 
            //FilesList.Add(new Files(d.Object.name, d.Object.size.ToString()));                
        });
 }
```

as I mentioned in comment code works perfectly if I don't do the list adding operation but what's the point of doing only `debug.Writeline()`

**What is going wrong**

If I comment the line `FilesList.Add(new Files(d.Ob...`, lambda expression (whole d=>{} part) executes 13 times which is totally excepted result

**if I uncomment the line `FilesList.Add(new Files(d.Ob...`, lambda expression (whole d=>{} part) only executes once and that is a issue for me.**

**Question**: how do I update my list every time data is updated ?

Comment: You don't say what is going wrong? Also, can you explain why you're using Rx here?

Comment: @Enigmativity added my issue, I am not using Rx but the plugin I added for firebase uses Rx

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. Can you describe what is going wrong when it only executes once? How do you know it's executing once? Are you getting any errors? Is it completing normally, but only adding one file to the list etc? You need a clear statement as to how it is failing.

Comment: Also the call `.AsObservable<fileInfo>()` is what is causing firebase to use Rx. If you took out that call you probably could just use a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Silly me. Forgot to add 'new' keyword. This is what happens when you start practising without through understanding of language.